# Set the trace id on request before filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-webflux

Hello I have one code of WebFilter that logs the requests and responses from my application but I want to add a trace-id on first request to the application, but it's not appearing:

```
Request:
2019-05-06 14:23:23.590 INFO [application,,,] 4151 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.m.m.shared.filters.RequestFilter : msg="Request to Application", path=/v1/car/1111", 

Response:
2019-05-06 14:23:28.196 INFO [application,f1dd6a9997339ht6,f1cc6ff0gg7969306,false] 4151 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.m.m.shared.filters.RequestFilter : msg="Response from Application", status_code="OK",
```

As you see on my response I have the trace-id, but in the request I do not have.

Is there a way to log the request with the trace id?

Here's my code I try to implement.

```
@Component
@Order(TraceWebFilter.ORDER + 5)
class RequestFilter implements WebFilter {
    private Tracer tracer;

    private CustomLogger logger = new CustomLogger(RequestFilter.class);

    public RequestFilter(Tracer tracer) {
        this.tracer = tracer;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {

        Span currentSpan = this.tracer.currentSpan();
        if (currentSpan != null) {
            serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders().add("TRACE-ID", currentSpan.context().traceIdString());
        }

        logger.info("Request to Application")
            .add("path", serverWebExchange.getRequest().getPath().pathWithinApplication().value())
            .add("headers", serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders().toString())
            .log();

        serverWebExchange.getResponse().beforeCommit(() -> {
            Span currentSpan2 = this.tracer.currentSpan();
            if (currentSpan2 != null) {
                serverWebExchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("TRACE-ID", currentSpan2.context().traceIdString());
            }
            logger.info("Response from Application").add("status_code", serverWebExchange.getResponse().getStatusCode()).log();
            return Mono.empty();
        });

        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    }
}
```

My request:

```
Expected: 2019-05-06 14:23:28.196 INFO [application,f1dd6a9997339ht6,f1cc6ff0gg7969306,false] 4151

Actual: 2019-05-06 14:23:23.590 INFO [application,,,]
```